# How do I fix this sed problem with unterminated lines?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, sed

I'm guessing this has to be an escaping issue, but I can't find it. What's most frustrating is that this is based on an old [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) script I used that worked, so why can't I make it work when I try to re-use it a year later? ;)

Framework:

I have a file with a list of filenames in it that all need the same 
string of HTML searched and replaced.

I need to replace

```
 <a href="foo.html">Foo</a>
```

with

```
<a href="foo.html">Foo</a><a href="bar.html">Bar</a>
```

I was using:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat sourcelist); do cat $i | sed 's,<a href="foo.html">Foo</a>,<a href="foo.html">Foo</a><a href="bar.html">Bar</a>,g'  > $i.bak ; mv $i.bak $i ; done
#end
```

But I'm getting the sed error "unterminated `s' command".

I've tried escaping the double quotes, the slashes, both, and still can't get it to parse.

It's late, and I'm losing focus. Any sharp eyes out there that can catch what I'm missing?

Comment: It runs just fine. Are you doing the replacement exactly as above or is just an example with foo and bar (perhaps you have an extra comma somewhere?)

Comment: Instead of trying to escape things, why not try eliminating them? Try using BAR as your replacement text, matching the first tag alone, matching "foo.html" alone, matching .html alone. Simplify until sed stops complaining, then see what the problem was.

Comment: Good point Beta, tackling it all at once isn't always the best idea. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try not to use a for loop with cats like that due to space problems. Also, the cat to sed is useless.

```
while read -r line
do
    sed 's,<a href=\"foo.html\">Foo</a>,<a href=\"foo.html\">Foo</a><a href=\"bar.html\">Bar</a>,g' "${line}" > "${line}.bak"
    mv "${line}.bak" "${line}"
done < sourcelist
```

Of course, if you are using GNU sed, there is the -i option to create backups for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the quotation marks? e.g:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat sourcelist); do cat $i | sed 's,<a href=\"foo.html\">Foo</a>,<a href=\"foo.html\">Foo</a><a href=\"bar.html\">Bar</a>,g'  > $i.bak ; mv $i.bak $i ; done
#end
```

Comment: you dont need to escape the double quotations in here

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by running Amro's while loop in a for:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(cat sourcelist); do

while read  line
do
    sed 's,<a href=\"foo.html\">FOO</a>,<a href=\"foo.html\">FOO</a>
    <a href=\"bar.html\">Bar</a>,g'
        done < $i > $i.bak ; mv $i.bak $i ; done
```

May not be the most elegant, but it works.

Cheers.

Comment: Why have you taken out two separate IDs?

Comment: First, it wasn't really my solution, I just added a fix. Second, we are assuming that the `sourcelist` file contains file names one per line. The reason for the while loop is to avoid the problem of spaces in file names. Your code above doesnt make sense to me?

Comment: sourcelist is one filename per line, you are correct Amro. Readline from the file didn't work as expected, so I thought I'd populate it as a variable to see if it worked which it did. I don't have the knowledge level to explain it, only to say that of all the examples given this one works. ;)